# Does NgRx Component Store turn dumb components into smart ones?

Tags: angular

The idea of smart and dumb (aka presentational) components is great, and I depend on it to structure my code properly. However, in this [article](https://ngrx.io/guide/component-store/usage), the team of NgRx are using the Component Store to manage the state of a toggle component. Personally, I think a toggle component is *dumb*. All it does is emitting its new value when toggled.

### My question:

Does that justify using the Component Store in a dumb component? And does that make it a smart one?
However, they mentioned they are using it to manage the **local UI state.** So, is this the only case we can use a store in a dumb component?

Comment: I can't speak on whether that's a good or a bad thing lol but yea pretty much by the definition you are right, if the toggle component injects the store for state, by the definition it would turn into a smart component. It would be still dumb if it only emitted the events and received the value over a (smart) parent component. (which is how I personally prefer it)

Comment: @mchl18 I think the whole thing is full of ambiguity. It seems like there's no _best practice_ concerning state management

Comment: You are right, although I think they are just showcasing here how it would work. I think it is still best practice to make these components dumb for the purpose of reuse.

Comment: @mchl18 I think it's still dumb. After all, the component still takes input and emits actions. I also think reactive coding is great in general. But in this case, I think they're just adding complexity.

Comment: I will try to refactor my current project and use that approach. Maybe it's better but I can't see that